# HTML a element doesn't expand to parent li dimensions

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal nav bar, and my **a** elements are not expanding to be the width & height of the parent **li** element.

How can I fix my CSS so that the **a** elements are as wide & tall as the outer/parent **li** element?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
        #navbar {
            width: 450px;
            height: 40px;
            background-color: RGB(112,112,112);
            list-style: none;
        }

        #navbar li {
            width: 112.5px;
            height: 40px;
            display: inline; 
            float: left;
        }

        #navbar li a {
            color: white;
            width: 112.5px;
            height: 40px;
        }

        #navbar a:link {
            background-color: red;
        }

        #navbar a:visited {
            background-color: purple;
        }

        #navbar a:active {
            background-color: green;
        }
        #navbar a:hover {
            background-color: blue;
        }
    -->
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <ul id="navbar">
        <li><a href="">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">contact us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">about us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">other</a></li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you considered using the `<nav>` element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By making all `a` elements `display:block`

**But why, sdleihssirhc? Why?**

Because the `<a>` element is an inline element by default, which means (among many, many other things) you cannot give it a width or a height. If you try, the browser will ignore you.

Answer (score 1):

Make all `a` elements `display: inline-block`.

It combines the best of both worlds - you can put them side-by-side without the need for `float`, and give them whatever `width` and `height` you choose. You can even use `vertical-align` to determine how it should be aligned with surrounding text!

Answer (score 1):

I have indented the additional lines to help with appearance. The `a` elements must be set to `display:block` as mentioned by sdleihssirhc. Notice also that by adding some padding to the top ( and subtracting from the overall height of the block) we have some vertical centering as well.

---

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#navbar {
    width: 450px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: RGB(112,112,112);
    list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
}

#navbar li {
    width: 112.5px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline; 
    float: left;
}

#navbar li a {
        display: block;
        float:left;
        padding-top: 6px;
        text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 112.5px;
    height: 34px;
}

#navbar a:link {
    background-color: red;
}

#navbar a:visited {
    background-color: purple;
}

#navbar a:active {
    background-color: green;
}
#navbar a:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
-->
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your CSS as follows:

```
#navbar li a {
...
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
...
}
```